# Mapping text in one column to text in other column

Tags: python, regex, pandas

I have a csv with a column containing titles in various forms. I need to map all ceo, chief operating officer, coo, cmo, etc. to 'C-Level'; vp, svp, vice president to 'vp-svp' in another column.

I have tried mapping titles with numbers but wasn't able to do so, and also think there might be an easier way to do so. I also want to do them all in one column, rather than having 2 columns for C-Level and VP-SVP when mapping them.

Attached is the expected result.

How do I solve the problem?

[image]

Comment: You add expected output, but not what your original data looks like..

Comment: My original data is a column of titles as I mentioned in description. So 6000 rows of the first column in the image above is the data I have.

Answer (score 0):

```
df['col'] = np.where(df.column1.isin(['ceo', 'chief operating officer', 'coo', 'cmo']), 'c-level','vp-svp')
```

Comment: Hi thanks! It partially works. It appears to be case-sensitive and also seems to be accepting exact titles only. For example, I have a title of vp of corporate relations but unless that is fully specified, it doesn't read just the vp part of it and maps it to VP. Do you know the way for that?

Comment: concerning the case sensitive issue, you can add: df.column1.str.lower().

As vp of corporate relations is not in ['ceo', 'chief operating officer', 'coo', 'cmo'] the label should be vp-svp as expected

Comment: Ya I figured that, but searching for a part of title seems to be more complicated.

Comment: you need to find a general rule that map your input to your output, then define a a function f which return true if f(input)='c-level' false otherwise. Then np.where(df.column1.apply(f)), 'c-level','vp-svp')

Answer (score 0):

Define a dictionary such that Key is your requested result and the Values is **a list of possibilities.**

```
my_dict = {"C-LEVEL":['CHIEF',"THE CHIEF","MY CHIEF"],"VP-SVP":['VP','PRODUCT VP']}
```

to use a dummy data:

```
df=pd.DataFrame({"A":["CHIEF","MY CHIEF","VP","PRODUCT VP","THE CHIEF", "USER"]})

    A
0   CHIEF
1   MY CHIEF
2   VP
3   PRODUCT VP
4   THE CHIEF
5   USER
```

create a function that search for the KEY:

```
def yourfunc(value):
    for k,v in my_dict.items():
        if value in my_dict.get(k):
            return k
    return "N/A"
```

Lastly, apply your function with a lambda:

```
df['Result'] = df['A'].apply(lambda x: yourfunc(x))
```

desired result:

```
          A       Result
0   CHIEF        C-LEVEL
1   MY CHIEF     C-LEVEL
2   VP           VP-SVP
3   PRODUCT VP   VP-SVP
4   THE CHIEF    C-LEVEL
5   USER         N/A
```

When you'll see **"N/A"** result you'll know that you need to upgrade your dictionary.